# c++ syntax for initializing arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I came across this code fragment, it compiles fine with g++. I can understand what is happening, but is this valid c++ or an extension?

```
const char* msgs[] = 
{
    [0] = "message0",
    [1] = "message1"
};
```

Comment: It's perfectly legal, and very useful to initialze at certain index instead of whole array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid C syntax.  In C you may use so-called *designators.*

```
designator:
    [ constant-expression ]
    . identifier
```

One more example

```
struct A
{
   int x;
   int y;
} a = { .x = 10, .y = 20 };
```

However it is not valid in C++. In C++ you should write

```
const char* msgs[] = 
{
    "message0",
    "message1"
};
```

If a C++ compiler compiles the declaration you showed then it is its own language extension that is not C++ compliant.